# How to add to an existing string and add it to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, listview, url

i am currently trying to edit this url (https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/i), where i are numbers 2 through to 222, and everytime a new number is put into that url, it saves the new url into a list. Are there any possible ways of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where did it fail? You could learn a lot by answering these questions

Comment: `'https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/' + str(i)`

Comment: i tired creating doing https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/i and created a loop where i = i +1, (setting i = 2) until it reached 222. however it said it needs str not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your problem if I don't get it wrong.

```
URL_LIST = []
for i in range(2,222,1):
    URL_LIST.append(f"https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/{i}")
```

or list comprehension way

```
url_list = [f"https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/{i}" for i in range(2,222,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension combined with `fstrings`:

```
out = [f'https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/{i}' for i in range(2, 222)]
print(out)
```

or use `+` for concatenating the strings as:

```
out = ['https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/' + str(i) for i in range(2, 222)]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if this is what you mean, but according to what I think you can do it like below

```
base = "https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/i"
list = []
for x in range(2, 222):
  list.append(base + str(x))
  
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code:

```
URL_LIST = []


for i in range(2,223):
    i = str(i)
    Url = "https://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Public/Missions/" + i
    URL_LIST.append(Url)



print(URL_LIST) 

certain_string = URL_LIST[0] 
print(certain_string)
```

The last two lines of code can be used to access the specific string in the list starting from 0 to 222.

Important:

- The range of the *for* loop must be until 223 to include 222 in the strings